# How equation in three variables can be parametrized into one variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I came up with a following proof that the gradient is perpendicular to the tangent
to any curve that lies on the level surface.

The proof goes like this.

Let $r = g(t)i + h(t)j + l(t)k$ is a smooth curve on the level surface $f(x,y,z) = C$ of a differentiable f, then

$ \hspace{7cm}  f(g(t), h(t), l(t) ) = C$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t to $t$ we get,

$ \frac{d(f(g(t), h(t), l(t) ))}{dt} = \frac{d(C)}{dt} $

$ \frac{\delta f}{\delta x} \frac{dg}{dt} + \frac{\delta f}{\delta y} \frac{dh}{dt} + \frac{\delta f}{\delta z} \frac{dl}{dt} = 0$

$ \nabla f. (\frac{dr}{dt}) = 0  $

$ \nabla f \perp (\frac{dr}{dt}) $

My doubt is not the proof. My doubt is different.

They have represented $ x, y, z $ as a function of $ g, h, l $.

If it is 2d we can represent in one variable example,

$ x^2 + y^2 = 4 $, then

$ x =2 \cos t , y = 2 \sin t$

Now take 3 variable function.

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$. In this equation (sphere eqn) we cannot write $ x,y,z $ in terms of one variable function. We can only write in terms of 2 variable. i.e.,

$ x = 2 \cos v \cos u , y = 2 \sin v \sin u , z = 2 \cos u$

So, we cant have a parametrized form in one variable. I would like to know what am I missing

Comment: A curve is basically one dimensional. Just because it is in a space of dimension 3 doesn't make it need more than one variable to describe it, just three functions of that variable.

Comment: Could you please explain how its coming down to 1d curve? If (x, y, z) satisfy (g, h, l) (in a function f). I mean why cannot it be a surface? please explain

Comment: Your curve depends on a single real number $t$ which can be viewed as time. And the curve is reasonably "smooth" which locally keeps its trace having a single dimension. True, there are "space-filling continuous curves" but these are wildy non-differentiable. A smooth curve when traced can be imagined as the movement of a fly going around some multididimensional space. He can never cover all of space, not in a finite time anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y,z)=((g(t),h(t),l(t))$ is not a parametrization of the whole 2-dimensional level surface, it's only a parametrization of a 1-dimensional curve on that surface.

Comment: Could you please explain how its coming down to 1d curve? If (x, y, z) satisfy (g, h, l) (in a function f).  I mean why cannot it be a surface? please explain

Comment: That question is quite different from the one you asked originally! But by assumption the coordinates depend smoothly on $t$, which rules out weirdnesses like “space-filling curves”; compare  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topological_curve and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Differentiable_curve.